# pyodbc cursor: what is the character limit to the query string?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I have three related questions:

- *What are the **limits** to the query string executed by a pyodbc cursor?*
- *Are they **server-specific**?*
- *Where is the governing standard, whatever it is, **documented**?*

I have tested up to 50k characters successfully, although the question stands.

Comment: what error do you get? How many values, if any, are you passing in the query string? It would be helpful if you paste your query here. You are right about pyodbc documentation, it is very minimal and some user questions doesn't seem to be answered as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a call to *SQLGetInfo()* with infoType **SQL_MAX_STATEMENT_LEN**.  This will provide you with the following information:

*An SQLUINTEGER value specifying the maximum length (number of characters, including white space) of an SQL statement. If there is no maximum length or the length is unknown, this value is set to zero.*

You can download the ODBC Help Guide for more details which is contained in the Microsoft Data Access SDK development kit; downloadable from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21995

Comment: Is there a way to increase this limit?