# error when passing with certain number of parameters to stored procedure using PYODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Hope that someone could help me with the following :
I'm calling a stored procedure from Python - 3.8.3 - with the following code

```
def set_param_days(self, cursor, valueWW):
    # valueWW = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', 
                '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25']
    query = 'exec [dbo].[SetOUTPUT] @dInervals=%s' % (valueWW,)
    cursor.execute(query)
```

However when executing this code i receive the following error :

```
cursor.execute(query)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with ''1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23',' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Initially, I thought the error has something to do with the stored procedure in SQL server, but upon further testing I completely changed the stored procedure name to none existing one and received the same exact error, meaning the error has Something to do with PYODBC or python code - the call never reached SQL server-

**Important**: the code will execute fine with no issue at all if the number of parameters didn't exceed 23!

Comment: store valueWW as a string separated by `,` like vaueWW = "1,2,3,4....22, 23".  This will shorten the length of your string. You have 46 unnecessary ' '.

Comment: Will give that a try, the issue is that i have a similar SP which i know for sure that i'll pass >300 parameter , is there any info on how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517363/pyodbc-cursor-what-is-the-character-limit-to-the-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = 'exec [dbo].[SetOUTPUT] @dInervals=\'%s\'' % ",".join(valueWW)
```

Comment: if you print the original query (in the querstion), you'll get `exec [dbo].[SetOUTPUT] @dInervals=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25']` . the value within the square brackets [] is the name of a sql object which could be max 128chars (the reason for the original error...besides the fact the procedure cannot be executed that way)

Comment: one more thing please, what if the parameters contains string, ex: Acgh123
how to wrap the parameters around single quote without exceeding the max chars ?