# Insert multiple rows in SQL Server table with single INSERT / single triggering of trigger

Tags: python, sql-server, triggers, pyodbc

## What I want

To be able to insert multiple rows into a table, in SQL Server, using python, and have my `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger only triggered when all rows have been inserted.

## Background

I have an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on my table which performs actions on previously unseen data.

The usual mode of operation is that periodically, multiple rows are inserted at a time.

When I'm inserting from python (using `pyodbc`), if I use:

```py
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO table_name VALUE (?, ?, ...)', list_of_lists)
```

The trigger will be triggered for every row - not what I want.

**I'm currently using:**

```py
sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (...),(...)...;'  # string built with format-strings
cursor.execute(sql)
```

This theoretically opens me up to SQL injection, but my environment is locked down so not really an issue.
Also,  I don't know what the max limit for the query string is.
I've tried to find the limit out using [the method in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517363/pyodbc-cursor-what-is-the-character-limit-to-the-query-string), but I get back an empty result. So I'm not sure if there is no limit or if it is unknown.

The number of rows I'd be inserting at a time isn't expected to be crazy (no more than 1-2k rows, handful of columns). So I don't imagine I'd hit a limit but I don't want to be surprised later.

There is then the option of `BULK INSERT` with the `FIRE_TRIGGERS` option, but that would require uploading my data as a file to the machine running SQL Server. This is complexity that I would like to avoid.

Is there a better option or is my current solution fine?

Comment: Have you considered using a table type parameter?

Comment: @Larnu no I haven't. My SQL-fu is pretty weak. What would that look like?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft not true. I demonstrate using one in my answer, and the on the answer I cite there is another answer confirming the version support was added.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could use a Table Type Parameter to do this. I will note that my Python is not great, so I don't know if you can do this *without* using a Stored Procedure.

Anyway, firstly let's create a sample table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            SomeString varchar(10),
                            SomeInt int,
                            SomeDate date,
                            SomeGUID uniqueidentifier);
GO
```

And then a sample type. I am intentionally omitting `SomeGUID`:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.SomeType AS table (SomeString varchar(10),
                                   SomeInt int,
                                   SomeDate date);
```

You'll then need to create a procedure that accepts the above `TYPE` as a parameter. In the below I've defined a static value for the entire data set for `SomeGUID` to demonstrate that all the rows are inserted in a single call to the proc in the final result set:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.SomeProc @SomeData dbo.SomeType READONLY AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @UID uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeString, SomeInt, SomeDate, SomeGUID)
    SELECT SomeString,
           SomeInt,
           SomeDate,
           @UID
    FROM @SomeData;
END;
GO
```

Now the python. For this I wrote the simple script below, referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156422/2029983) for some help. I've included the whole script for a full working solution, though obviously some won't be applicable to your script and you might not be using an environmental file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#Import the bare minimums for this to work
import pyodbc, os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

#Get the details from my environemental file
load_dotenv()
SQLServer = os.getenv('SQL_SERVER')
SQLDatabase = os.getenv('SQL_DATABASE')
SQLLogin = os.getenv('SQL_LOGIN')
SQLPassword = os.getenv('SQL_PASSWORD')

#Create the full connection string
SQLConnString = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=' + SQLServer + ';Database=' + SQLDatabase + ';UID='+ SQLLogin +';PWD=' + SQLPassword

#Define the data that is going to be inserted into the table.
MyData = [('abc',1,'20200527'),('def',2,'20210527')]
#Turn it into a tuple. explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156422/2029983
params = (MyData,) 

#And then execute the procedure, passing params as the parameters; which is a table
with pyodbc.connect(SQLConnString,timeout=20) as sqlConn:
    with sqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('EXEC dbo.SomeProc ?;', params)
        sqlConn.commit()
```

And then, when I run a `SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable` I get the below data:

| ID | SomeString | SomeInt | SomeDate | SomeGUID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 | 2020-05-27 | 945a3656-54ee-47a2-962c-7a34c7f50635 |
| 2 | def | 2 | 2021-05-27 | 945a3656-54ee-47a2-962c-7a34c7f50635 |

Comment: The SELECT query should work without a stored procedure.  You're just sending a TSQL batch with a parameter.  Still must create the Table Type, though.

Comment: I've personally, however, got no idea how you define the data to into the `TYPE` with just s `SELECT` @DavidBrowne-Microsoft .`cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(SomeString,SomeInt,SomeDate) SELECT * FROM ?;', params)` for example, does not work.

Comment: Interesting.  In .NET you must specify the table type in the client's SqlParameter.  Perhaps pyodbc is looking at the stored procedure parameters to determine the table type.

Comment: That's what I would assumed, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft . I haven't run a trace on the above the confirm; I might later if my curiosity gets the better of me.

Comment: Yep, that it [*exactly*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkxWX.gif) what is does, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft .

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to come back to you. Thanks, this looks promising, however I don't like the fact that I have to create a type like that. I prefer a more generic solution. I may explore trying to use JSON as per one of David Browne's previous comments.