# pyodbc send parameter as nvarchar

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, parameter-passing, pyodbc

I have a query with multiple parameters that I need to run using pyodbc and I have an issue.
This is a simplified version of the query, with only one parameter (I actually have 6)

```
declare @alertTypeName nvarchar(255)
set @alertTypeName = ?
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM AlertType WHERE Name = @alertTypeName
```

@alertTypeName can have special characters, for example 'Boli şi Dăunători'.
Naturally, if I were to run this query directly in SQL Server I would set `@alertTypeName = N'Boli şi Dăunători'`. The SELECT does not return anything without adding N in front of the text.
My problem is, how do I send the value as parameter to the query in `cursor.execute()` so it will be correctly encoded?

This is python my code at the moment (simplified version):

```
query = textwrap.dedent(""" 
declare @alertTypeName nvarchar(255)
set @alertTypeName = ?
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM AlertType WHERE Name = @alertTypeName
""")

[...]
alertTypeName = "Boli şi Dăunători"

[...]
    
paramValues = [syswinAlertId, code, alertTypeName, alertMessage, createdBy, modifiedBy]
cursor.execute(query, paramValues)
```

alertTypeName can have different values depending on some conditions, so I cannot just add it directly to the query text.

Comment: Can we assume that you are running Python 3.x?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode) may help.

Comment: @GordThompson yes, i'm using 3.8

Comment: @Zhorov cnxn.setencoding('utf-8') doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 all strings are Unicode, so if you pass a string as a parameter value then pyodbc will relay it to the ODBC Driver Manager (DM) in the appropriate format to be recognized as Unicode. For example, if we start a SQL Server Profiler trace and then run this code

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=mssqlLocal")
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT ? AS thing"
params = ("Boli şi Dăunători",)
result = crsr.execute(sql, params).fetchval()
```

we'll see that SQL Server is interpreting the parameter value as an N'string'

```sql
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(34)',N'SELECT @P1 AS thing',N'Boli şi Dăunători'
select @p1
```

Note that we **do not** need to mess with `.setencoding()` and `.setdecoding()`; the pyodbc defaults are the correct ones for SQL Server

Comment: Does pyodbc really use `sp_prepexec` rather than `sp_executesql`, wow? That prevents parameter sniffing

Comment: @Charlieface - pyodbc calls the standard ODBC function `SQLExecute`. It is up to the ODBC driver to decide what database-specific method to use on the back-end.

Comment: Hehe, have a look at how it (Python) [handles Table type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724536/insert-multiple-rows-in-sql-server-table-with-single-insert-single-triggering#comment119709206_67725115) in the background then, @Charlieface . ;)

Comment: OK I'll rephrase that: does the official SQL Server ODBC driver really use `sp_prepexec`? @Larnu That's just gross...

Comment: Yes, yes it does, @Charlieface .

Comment: @GordThompson then there must be another reason that my code doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problem was actually caused by a faulty if condition in the code, and not by SQL. Thanks everyone for helping.